# How to inner join(filtering for nested properties) with expression tree?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inner-join, expression-trees

My users should be able to configure a filter to get a result from the database.
I decided to use an expression tree, to be flexible with the query. But I have problems with the expression tree for filtering by ReferenceCode.

## Entities:

### PumpStartUp

- Duration (TimeSpan)
- DutDbId (Guid/FK)
- TimeStamp (DateTime)
- DUT (DeviceUnderTest)

### DeviceUnderTest

- AdminId (string/unique)
- DbId (Guid/PK)
- ReferenceCode (string)
- StartUps (List)

Here is a part of the filter in equivalent linq. But linq I can't use, because I don't know how many ReferenceCodes will be defined by the user.:

```
//-------------------reference code filter---------------------------
var query = context.PumpStartUps.Where((p => p.DUT.ReferenceCode == "HKR566" ||
                                             p.DUT.ReferenceCode == "HSH967" ||
                                             .
                                             .
                                             .));
startUps = query.ToList();
```

For filtering by DeviceUnderTest part of the filter, my solution is:

```
// --------------------duts filter-----------------------------------
Expression dutsExpression = null;
Expression psuExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PumpStartUp), "psu");
Expression psuDutIdExpression = Expression.Property(psuExpression, "DutDbId");

foreach (var dut in filter.Duts)
{
    DeviceUnderTest deviceUnderTest = context.DevicesUnderTest.Where(d => d.AdminId == dut.Id).Single();
    Expression dutIdExpression = Expression.Constant(deviceUnderTest.DbId);
    Expression dutExpression = Expression.Equal(pumpStartUpDutIdExpression, dutIdExpression);
    if (dutsExpression == null)
    {
        dutsExpression = dutExpression;
    }
    else
    {
        dutsExpression = Expression.Or(dutsExpression, dutExpression);
    }
}
```

How can I filter by ReferenceCode in that manner:

Comment: Please edit the title, it's not an inner-join, what this question is about, is to create expressions for nested properties.

Comment: Yes, but the generated SQL will be a join. Is this not right?

Comment: Yes, for every navigation property a join query will be generated. I think the title is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var dutExpression = Expression.Property(psuExpression, "DUT");
var referenceCodeExp = = Expression.Property(dutExpression, "ReferenceCode ");
var constExpr = Expression.Constant("HKR566");
var eqExp = Expression.Equal(referenceCodeExp , constExpr);
dutsExpression = Expression.Or(dutsExpression, eqExp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited amount of codes, you can always say

```
var query = context.PumpStartUps.Where(p => codes.Contains(p.DUT.ReferenceCode))
```

This works up until about 2000 parameters. If you need more, then you should probably send the codes somehow to a temp table (or rather a function returning a table, since ef does not support temp tables), and join on that since constructing an expression with more than 2000 ors is not gonna perform well.